# 'map['projectId'] != null': 'projectId' cannot be null , the error appeared while using firebase core to initialize app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I used firebasecore to initializeApp, but here it prints me an error message in terminal

```
   void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MaterialApp(home:MyApp()));
}
```

The error thrown

```
E/flutter (18553): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/firebase_options.dart': Failed assertion: line 64 pos 16: 'map['projectId'] != null': 'projectId' cannot be null.
E/flutter (18553): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
E/flutter (18553): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
E/flutter (18553): #2      new FirebaseOptions.fromMap (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/firebase_options.dart:64:16)
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you are running it mobile device or emulator, make sure you added the `google-services.json` file to your project.
- If you are running on web, make sure you added those configurations to your `index.html`.
- If you are initializing a secondary Firebase app inside your project, regardless if web or mobile, make sure you passed all the required parameters to your initialization options, like this:

```
Firebase.initializeApp(
        name: 'SecondaryFirbaseApp',
        options: FirebaseOptions(
            appId: 'your app id',
            apiKey: 'your app key',
            messagingSenderId: 'your messagingSenderId',
            projectId: 'your projectId',
            storageBucket: 'your storageBucket',
            authDomain: 'your authDomain'),
      );
```

You get all the fields in the above code which start with `your`, from your firebase project console screen.